# Explaining performance difference in two nearly identical algorithms

Tags: c++, performance, vector, benchmarking

This question is rather vague and I don't really *need* an answer to it, but I am very curious about what the answer might be, so I'll ask it anyway.

I have an algorithm which generates a huge amount of matrices. It later runs a second algorithm over it which generates a solution. I ran it 100 times and it took an average of ~17 seconds.

The second algorithm does nearly exactly the same, with the only difference being, that the second algorithm is run over each matrix as soon as it is generated, so that they actually never need to be stored anywhere. This variant obviously needs much less space, which is why I made it, but it also needs an average of only ~2 seconds for the same problem.

I didn't expect it to run faster, especially not that much.

The code is quite big, so I will try to outline the difference in something resembling pseudo-code:

```
recursiveFill(vector<Matrix> &cache, Matrix permutation) {
  while(!stopCondition) {
    // generate next matrix from current permutation
    if(success)
      cache.push_back(permutation);
    else
      recursiveFill(cache, permutation);
    // some more code
  }
}

recursiveCheck(Matrix permutation) {
  while(!stopCondition) {
    // alter the matrix some
    if(success)
      checkAlgorithm(permutation);
    else
      recursiveCheck(permutation);
    // some more code
  }
}
```

After the recursive fill, a loop runs the checkAlgorithm over all elements in the cache. Everything I didn't include in the code is identical in both algorithms. I guessed that the storing in the vector is what eats up all the time, but if i recall correctly, the size of a c++ vector doubles each time it is overfilled, so a reallocation shouldn't happen too often.
Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, have no idea what you're asking. However, the overhead of std::vector isn't merely when the array is re-sized and therefore copied (though that plays into it) but also your elements must be copy-able to even use std::vector, so unless you're storing pointers or references, you're getting full deep copies pushed into the vector.

Comment: What does `cachegrind` (the cache checking tool of `valgrind`, you activate it by adding `--tool=cachegrind` to the commandline) say to your two codes?

Comment: It really depends on the implementation. I'd guess that you're not only generating cache misses but page table misses as well, in which the OS is being thrashed to constantly have to translate virtual addresses back and forth because the recursive calls in the first one are of a different, less sequential order than the

Comment: What is `Matrix`? Does it use heap allocation? Is it movable (and does your compiler support move semantics)? Is swap correctly overloaded and implemented efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the additional time is due to the copying of matrices within the `vector`. With the times you give, one pass through the data takes 20 or 170 ms, which is on the right order of magnitude for a lot of copying.

Remember that, even though the overhead of copying due to reallocations of the vector is linear, every inserted matrix is copied twice on average, once during insertion, and once during reallocation. In conjunction with the cache clobbering effect of copying a large amount of data, this can produce the additional runtime.

Now you might say: But I'm also copying the matrices when I pass them to the recursive call, shouldn't I expect the first algorithm to take at most three times the time of the second one?
The answer is, that any recursive decent perfectly cache friendly if it is not hampered by cache utilization for data on the heap. Thus, almost all the copying done in the recursive decent does not even reach the L2 cache. If you clobber your entire cache from time to time by doing a `vector` reallocation, you will resume with an entirely cold cache afterwards.

Comment: this sounds interesting. So filling a container with a recursion might be a lot slower than filling it in a simple loop? Also, I explained something wrong, 17 and 2 seconds wasn't the time for one function call, but for the complete problem, which is to examine a tree of branching factor 5 and depth 10, so the total amount of generated (and in one case cached) matrices is 19.531.249 per run of the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the numbers, that is precisely the order of magnitude that I assumed it would be :-) And, yes, I read your 17 seconds correctly, that's why I divided this time by 100 to get to 170 milliseconds.

Comment: ah, then I understood you wrong. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

The culprit here is probably temporal locality. You CPU cache is only so big, so when you save off everything after each run and come back to it later, it has left your CPU caches in the meanwhile and takes longer (10s to 100s of cycles) to access. With the second method, it's right there in L1 (or possibly MMX registers) and takes only a cycle or two to access.

In optimization, you generally want to think like the Wu-Tang Clan: Cache Rules Everything Around Me.

[Some people have done testing on this](http://kjellkod.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/why-you-should-never-ever-ever-use-linked-list-in-your-code-again/), and copies in cache are often *much* cheaper than dereferences into main memory.

Comment: I think it's more than a bit premature to jump to this conclusion right off the bat. Not that you're wrong, but a 15-second difference is quite substantial, we know nothing of his cache sizes, we know nothing of his copy semantics, etc.

Comment: Copies in-cache may be cheaper than dereferences into main memory, but _you are drawing a false dichotomy_ by answering as though the copy is immaterial. We don't know where he's copying to or from; we haven't seen his implementation or his data sets. This answer may indeed be a part of the final solution, but as it stands this answer is akin to a medical doctor suggesting that a patient has the flu because he sneezed.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking a `vector` doesn't have to double each growth, it just needs to grow geometrically to supply the required amortized constant time.

In this case if you have sufficiently large number of matrices the growth and required data copies could still be the issue. Or it could be swapping to allocate enough memory. The only way to know for sure is to *profile* on the system where you experience this difference.